# How to change layout orientation to vertical if all child views will not fit horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I need to change the orientation of a Linearlayout depending on whether buttons would fit horizontally or not. For example, if we had two buttons that would fit within the total width of the screen, I would show them in a horizontal LinearLayout, but if they wouldn't fit, I need to show them in a vertical layout.

I tried the following code but because the third button resizes itself and starts going vertically to fit in the bounds, the child count ends up being still less than the width. Is there a way to calculate the width of the buttons without this change occurring?

```
mButtonsLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int childCount = mButtonsLayout.getChildCount();
                int childWidth = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++ ) {
                    View child = mButtonsLayout.getChildAt(i);
                    childWidth += child.getWidth();
                }

                if (mButtonsLayout.getMeasuredWidth() < childWidth) {
                    mButtonsLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                } else {
                    mButtonsLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                }

                ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = mButtonsLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
                if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
                    viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the way the third button has changed itself to fit. **My wanted outcome is** that if all buttons will not fit horizontally, change the orientation to vertical so the buttons appear on top of each other.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [library](https://github.com/lankton/android-flowlayout)

```
 <cn.lankton.flowlayout.FlowLayout
        android:id="@+id/flowlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:lineSpacing="10dp"
        android:background="#F0F0F0">

</cn.lankton.flowlayout.FlowLayout>
```

gradle

```
compile 'cn.lankton:flowlayout:latest version'
```

[image]

Here is a another library to arrange view's programetically..

[FlexBox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: As today ConstraintLayout 2.0 implemented a helper named [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) to do exactly the same

See: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/constraintlayout-flow-simple-grid-building-without-nested-layouts/

---

This doesn't answer to your question, but I think is a very good option to achieve that you would want to.

Using Google's [flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) it allow you to arrange your buttons automatically if there is no place horizontally.

Hope it will be usefull